# How to convert immutable Seq to mutable seq with until loop

Tags: scala, sequence, immutability, mutable

I'm trying to return a mutable Sequence with an until loop, but i have an immutable seq in return of (0 until nbGenomes) :

```
 def generateRandomGenome(nbGenomes:Int): IndexedSeq[GenomeDouble]={
    return ((0 until nbGenomes toSeq).map{e => generateRandomGenome}) 
  }
```

Return compilation error :

```
found   : scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[org.openmole.tools.mgo.mappedgenome.genomedouble.GenomeDouble]
 required: scala.collection.mutable.IndexedSeq[org.openmole.tools.mgo.mappedgenome.genomedouble.GenomeDouble]
    return ((0 until nbGenomes toSeq).map{e => generateRandomGenome})
```

How i can force the until loop to return an mutable seq ?
Thanks scala community!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can convert an immutable sequence to a mutable one by creating a new mutable sequence with the varargs constructor.

```
scala> val l = List(1,2,3)
l: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
scala> scala.collection.mutable.ArraySeq(l:_*)
res0: scala.collection.mutable.ArraySeq[Int] = ArraySeq(1, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 3):

If the compiler knows which collection type to expect (and it does here as indicated by the error message) you can use `scala.collection.breakOut` to allow the type to be inferred based on the expected type for the expression rather than the type of the collection itself.

```
def generateRandomGenomes(n: Int): collection.mutable.IndexedSeq[Double] =
  (0 until n).map(_ => util.Random.nextDouble())(collection.breakOut)
```

(I tweaked your example a bit to stick to well-known types.)

Most (all?) collection types have some handy factory methods on their companion objects.  So another way of accomplishing the same thing is to use `scala.collection.mutable.IndexedSeq.fill`:

```
def generateRandomGenomes(n: Int): collection.mutable.IndexedSeq[Double] =
  collection.mutable.IndexedSeq.fill(n)(util.Random.nextDouble())
```

Comment: Thanks for this explanation and other example :)